# Get value from dictionary (or json) based of another key value in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

I have a huge nested dictionary. Random levels deep full of nested lists and dictionaries.

Somewhere down deep there is a dictionary of a form:

{name:'jasdhsajkd', id:'23214rfrw4523rfew'}

What I want to do is search in all keys for value of id above but get the value of name.

Here is the json code for the dictionary:

[code](https://pastebin.com/9DYBKTTr)

```
{"categories": [{"child_filter_groups": [{"icon_url": "https://main.cdn.wish.com/web/000e72f28bfa/img/filtered_feed/filter_feed_filter_color.png", "id": "Color", "filters": [{"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_54089f882ee345121dfdddce", "name": "Bronze", "origin_name": "Bronze"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0734", "name": "Black", "origin_name": "Black"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0735", "name": "Blue", "origin_name": "Blue"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0736", "name": "Clear", "origin_name": "Clear"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0737", "name": "Gold", "origin_name": "Gold"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0738", "name": "Gray", "origin_name": "Gray"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0739", "name": "Green", "origin_name": "Green"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e073a", "name": "Multi-Color", "origin_name": "Multi-Color"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e073b", "name": "Orange", "origin_name": "Orange"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e073c", "name": "Pink", "origin_name": "Pink"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e073d", "name": "Red", "origin_name": "Red"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e073e", "name": "Silver", "origin_name": "Silver"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0740", "name": "White", "origin_name": "White"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc217e21a8632b3c6e0741", "name": "Yellow", "origin_name": "Yellow"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc237a21a863307923e697", "name": "Brown", "origin_name": "Brown"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_53dc36c521a86346c126eaf1", "name": "Purple", "origin_name": "Purple"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "color_54889a49f8a0b3363e0ba1ef", "name": "Beige", "origin_name": "Beige"}], "name": "Color"}, {"icon_url": "https://main.cdn.wish.com/web/000e72f28bfa/img/filtered_feed/filter_feed_filter_rating.png", "name": "Rating", "is_exclusive": true, "filters": [{"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "rating_4", "name": "\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2605 & up", "origin_name": null}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "rating_3", "name": "\u2605\u2605\u2605 & up", "origin_name": null}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "rating_2", "name": "\u2605\u2605 & up", "origin_name": null}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "filter_id": "rating_1", "name": "\u2605 & up", "origin_name": null}], "id": "Rating"}], "name": "Popular", "filter_id": "tabbed_feed_latest"}, {"wish_express_banner_info": "Get your Delivery by 18 Oct!", "name": null, "filter_id": "express__tab"}, {"red_dot_badge": true, "name": "Pickup", "filter_id": "pickup__tab"}, {"name": "Recently Viewed", "filter_id": "recently_viewed__tab"}, {"child_filter_groups": [], "red_dot_badge": true, "name": "Blitz Buy", "filter_id": "deal_dash__tab"}, {"child_filter_groups": [{"icon_url": ......................
```

Comment: Define a function that evaluates the value of a key and call this function recursively.

Comment: Are 'name' and 'id' unique in your dictionary or they can be found multiple times?

Comment: @IoaTzimas they can be found multiple times.

Comment: Ok, i have added an answer yesterday, please let me know if it works with your data. Cheers

Comment: @IoaTzimas I executed your code below. I got: s=txt
>>> k=[eval('{'+i.split('}')[0]+'}') for i in s.split('{') if i.startswith("'name'")]
>>> len(k)
0

Answer (score 0):

The following works on a string basis, probably there are better solutions that work on dict basis, but it can do the work. Exlanation in comments:

```
s=str(your_dict) #turns your dict to a string
k=[eval('{'+i.split('}')[0]+'}') for i in s.split('{') if i.startswith("'name'")] #searches for string parts that start with 'name' and save all the part as dictionary
[i['name'] for i in k if i['id']=='23214rfrw4523rfew'][0] #searches for the dictionary than has ht edesired id and returns the name
```

The code needs some consideration, as it works under strict rules. For example 'name' must be first key in your subdictionary and inside simple quotes. If it's in double quotes, then `i.startswith("'name'")` must be replaced by `i.startswith('"name"')`
If you can provide your full input, i could check if it works or adjust the code if it doesn't